# changing link_to parameters via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I got this link

```
<%= link_to "show replies", tweets_show_replies_path(:parent => tweet, active: false ), method: :post, remote: true, class: "show-replies" %>
```

and this function in my "tweets" controller

```
def show_replies

    @parent = Tweet.find(params[:parent])
    @tweet = Tweet.new

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {render :nothing => true}
        format.js
    end

end
```

and this is my **show_replies.js.erb**

```
$('#tweet-<%= @parent.id %>').find('.replies').append(' <%=j render "tweets/replies" %> ');
```

I'd need to change the "**active**" parametr to **true** and update it in my erb file. But I don't know how to read rails parametrs and change them via ajax.

Comment: I don't understand what rails parameters you need to read? Don't you just need to change the active to true  in the .js.erb file when you show the replies (which can be done via Jquery)?

Comment: Actually I mean change the url of the link via Jquery (and you can use rails link_to helper in the .js.erb).

Comment: Can you include in your question the **rendered html** for your `link_to`?  This is what the javascript will be working on.  The rails helper version is actually irrelevant.

Comment: I can change it but then I don't know how to pass this updated value to the original link.

Comment: which rails parameter you want to pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd give the link an ID:

```
<%= link_to "show replies", tweets_show_replies_path(:parent => tweet, active: false ), method: :post, remote: true, id: "tweet-#{tweet.id}-replies-link", class: "show-replies" %>
```

Then do this in your show_replies.js.erb to change the href:

```
$("#tweet-#{@parent.id}-replies-link").attr("href", "<%= tweets_show_replies_path(:parent => @parent, active: true) %>");
```